# Утечка памяти C# System.Web.Http

Tags: c#, uwp, утечка-памяти

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с тем, что приложение начало "течь". Через профайлер нашёл проблемное место (в принципе, о нём я и без профайлера догадывался). Утечка происходит при запросе (GET / POST) к серверу. Посоветовали у HttpClient (использую более новый, увпшный) using не вызывать (изначально вызывал) и сделать его глобальным приватным филдом, но, как уже описалось выше, это чревато последствиями. Отсюда возникает вопрос: стоит ли убрать глобальный филд с HttpClient'ом и сделать его локальным, определив создание инстанса в дерективе using прям в методах Get / Post, как это делалось ранее ? Не сильно такое будет грузить ЦП ?

Кстати, реализация IDisposable здесь бессмысленна, в принципе, т.к. инстанс класса зарегистрирован в Unity контейнере синглтоном.

**UDP:**

Переписал с использованием юзингов. Результат тот же. Есть смысл переписать на C++ всю библиотеку для работы с АПИ ВК ?

**UDP 2:**

На скрине отметил то, что кушает память. Переживает все сборки мусора

```
namespace VKMoonlight.Core.VKServices
{
    internal class VKService : IVKService, IDisposable
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly int _clientId;
        private readonly string _clientSecret;
        private const string API_VERSION = "5.68";
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts; 
        #endregion


        public VKService(int clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            _clientId = clientId;
            _clientSecret = clientSecret;
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
        }


        #region Dependency 
        [Dependency]
        public ISerializationService SerializationService { get; protected set; }
        #endregion


        #region Methods 
        public void CancellAllPendingRequest()
        {
            _cts.Cancel(throwOnFirstException: true);
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
        }

        public async Task<Response<T>> Request<T>(string methodName, Dictionary<string, string> reqParams)
        {
            var response = default(T);
            ResponseError error = null;


            var parameters = reqParams ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters["access_token"] = Session?.Token ?? nameof(Session.Token);
            parameters["v"] = API_VERSION;

            try
            {
                var serverResponse = await Post(string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/{0}", methodName), parameters);

                response = SerializationService.Deserialize(serverResponse, jObj =>
                {
                    // действия
                });

                return new Response<T>(error, response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is VKServiceException || ex is VKServiceResponseException)
            {
                return new Response<T>(error, response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public async Task<string> Post(string url, Dictionary<string, string> paramsDict)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(paramsDict)).AsTask(cancellationToken: _cts.Token);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Возникла ошибка во время выполнения POST запроса", ex); 
            }
        }

        public async Task<string> Get(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).AsTask(cancellationToken: _cts.Token);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                throw ex; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new VKServiceException("Возникла ошибка во время выполнения GET запроса.", ex);
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region Non-public methods           
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _httpClient.Dispose();
            _cts.Dispose(); 
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кто посоветовал не вызвать using и как именно течет память? Продолжает бесконечно выедать память, гигабайтами, вплоть до OOM? или просто "после первого вызова памяти выедается чуть больше"?

Comment: @PashaPash, коллега. 
ну с юзингами ничего не изменилось. в бездействии примерно + 150 - 300 кб из машинного кода каждые 15 - 30сек. 
Течёт при лонг пуллинге, который крутится в бесконечном цикле. Возможно, есть смысл изменить сам лонг пулл, но пока не придумал, каким образом

Comment: не совсем уверен что такое "+150-300 килобайт из машинного кода" -
 это какой-то конкретный вид кучи? вам стоит показать минимальный пример для воспроизведения утечки, и заодно - скрины или еще-что-то из профайлера, по которым вы диагностируете утечку.

Comment: ну в UWP есть управляемая куча и машинная куча. Так вот машинная куча не очищается

скрин постараюсь залить сейчас

Answer (score 0):

Давно для сетевого взаимодействия в UWP использую [RestSharp.Portable](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable), чего и вам советую. Ничего не течет, всё работает как часики. Однажды была проблема с методом PUT в хитрой комбинации с OAuth, завел баг на гитхабе и починили.

Comment: да, библиотека действительно хорошая, но для этого проекта было решено сделать всё вручную (хотя и многовато делать пришлось).Так-то я и уже готовой либой для вк мог воспользоваться (VKNet, InTouch и тд). 
Из библиотек использую только юнити (IoC), который заменю в будущем своей реализацией, и Newtonsoft. Можете называть это эдаким моим забубоном :)